# Передать значения параметров из html в Controller в ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Стоит с виду простая задача: в веб приложении на ASP .Net Core есть html-страница, на странице таблица и два окошка выбора даты - начальная и конечная, а также кнопка "Найти". Код следующий:

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" value="2021-10-01" />
<input type="date" id="enddate" value="2021-10-10" />
<input type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
```

Также есть таблица, которая выдается через Controller при заходе на нужную страницу:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyPageWithTable(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
        {
            return View(await _dbcontext.Table.Where(x => x.pl_date_first>=startdate&&x.pl_date_first<=enddate).ToListAsync());
        }
```

На данный момент на странице показывается пустая таблица.
Вопрос следующий: как передать параметры `startdate` и `enddate` в метод `MyPageWithTable`, чтобы по выбору начальной и конечной даты в окошках и нажатию кнопки "Найти" в таблицу передавались записи за нужный период?
[image: PageTable]

Comment: используйте ajax, отправляйте post запрос средставми javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще для оформления таблиц и настройки фильтрации, можно использовать [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/), как это использовать именно для ASP.NET Core показано [вот здесь.](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_ElrxXYY_ZD88RpFFvfBHR) Это пример редизайна интернет-магазина на ASP.NET Core MVC на .NET 5, где также показано использование Syncfusion для оформления вывода данных в таблице, и настройка фильтрации. Но можно сделать проще, создавая еще один метод типа Post, который будет вызван при нажатии на кнопку "Найти", и в который передаются значения startdate и enddate. Внутри этого метода, снова вызывается метод MyPageWithTable, типа Get, но уже с новым диапазоном для дат.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал следующим образом:
Добавил к окошкам выбора даты и кнопке "Найти" html-форму post:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/MyPageWithTable">            
        <input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="2021-10-01" />
        <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="2021-10-22" />
        <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
</form>
```

Далее добавил в контроллере [HttpPost]:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyPageWithTable(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
    {            
        return View(await _dbcontext.Table.Where(x => x.pl_date_first >= startdate && x.pl_date_first <= enddate.Value.AddDays(1)).ToListAsync());
    }
```

Как итог - кнопка работает, даты ищутся.